# HTML "select" with fixed icon

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a select to choose a month. In the dropdown list I want to show just the name of the months (e.g. january, february). But in the box of the select (that shows the selected value) I want to show a FontAwesome icon (of a calendar) and then the name of the month selected.

That's how I want the select with the dropdown list closed look like

[image]

I got that but my dropdown list is like that

[image]

And I want it to be like that (without the calendar icon)

[image]

My code:

```
<select>
    <option value="all">&#xf133; All</option>
    <option value="m01">&#xf133; January</option>
    <option value="m02">&#xf133; February</option>
</select>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.

http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/qhCsJ/1/

It's exactly what you need to do. wrap your select in a container then give a background image with padding and no repeat, as you would do it for a text input.

```
<div class="selectParent">
     <select>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>           
     </select>  
 </div>
```

and then the css would be

```
.selectParent{
    width:80px;
    overflow:hidden;


}

.selectParent select{
    width:100px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 20px;
    border: none;
     background: transparent url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") no-repeat left center;

}
```